# Reading a file into an array, and skipping newlines

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, newline

Hey guys I am looking to read a file that has multiple newlines in it and transfer the file contents into an array. For instance:

File:

```
I want to  
Make This  
File Into  
An Array
```

and the file would be inserted into an array as (pseudo code):

```
array [] = iwanttomakethisfileintoanarray
```

I know how to skip spaces and change capitalization, and I have been using fscanf to scan the file and input the characters into the array.

My issue is that

```
while(fscanf(f, "%s",  array) != EOF)
```

breaks when it reaches a newline character.  I've searched around for a solution but have come up empty for now. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Read the file byte by byte and put alphabetical characters (see library function `isalpha`) into an array one by one.

Comment: That fscanf should treat newlines exactly same as spaces. Your issue is probably, that scanf returns 0 at some point.

Answer (score 2):

NEVER use the conversion specifier `"%s"` without a `width` to limit the number of characters that get written to the destination. eg. `"%99s"` to read 99 chars into an array of 100.

Reading the file word by word using `scanf()` just to get rid of whitespace is only compliating things since you would have to `tolower()` every character of each word anyway. Better read the file character by character in the first place:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

enum { BUFFER_GROWTH = 4 };

int main(void)
{
    char const *filename = "test.txt";
    FILE *input = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!input) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open \"%s\" for reading :(\n\n", filename);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_t length  = 0;
    size_t size    = 1;
    char  *buffer  = malloc(size * sizeof *buffer);
    for (int ch; (ch = fgetc(input)) != EOF;) {
        if (!isprint((char unsigned) ch) || isspace((char unsigned) ch))
            continue;

        if (length + 1 >= size) {
            char *tmp = realloc(buffer, (size *= BUFFER_GROWTH) * sizeof *buffer);
            if (!tmp) {
                free(buffer);
                fclose(input);
                fputs("Not enough memory :(", stderr);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            buffer = tmp;
        }

        buffer[length++] = tolower((char unsigned) ch);
    }
    buffer[length] = '\0';

    puts(buffer);

    free(buffer);
    fclose(input);
}
```

Comment: Upvote for all kinds of correctness, even though that `char unsigned` does hurt my eyes :D

Comment: Nitpick: This `char *tmp = realloc ...` could have "stayed" a `void*`.

Comment: Nitpick^2: And this `= calloc(1, 1);` more nicely would be `= calloc(size, sizeof *buffer);` or just `= malloc(size); buffèr[0]  = 0;`

Comment: @alk *Nitpik* – benefit? – *Nitpick^2* – accepted. There is also no need to set it zero.

Comment: "*Benefit*" but well mostly a matter of niceness, style.

Comment: @alk Yes, so it stays a `char*` ;p if only to be able to use `sizeof *buffer`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala *char unsigned does hurt my eyes :D* – it will stop hurting your eyes once you get into the habit or reaing declarations from right to left: `char unsigned const * const foo` *~>* `foo` is a `const` pointer to `const unsigned char`.